# What is the difference between Mitigate and Mollify?

Tags: meaning

I have a feeling that mollify is used with anger and other emotions while mitigate can be used with severity of something such as punishment.

> Mitigate: to lessen in severity or to appease
>
> Mollify: to calm; soothe; make less severe

Am I right? If not than could someone explain the difference to me.

Comment: you mitigate a problem, you mollify a person.

Comment: You are right generally. @Jim's comment is true usually, but it is possible to use mollify referring to reduce the severity of a situation too: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mollify)

Comment: Isn't "Mitigate" the scandal surrounding Walter Mitty?

Comment: An apology may both mitigate and mollify if the harm is hurt feelings.

Answer (score 4):

*[Mitigate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mitigate)*:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   1.0 Make (something bad) less severe, serious, or painful:
>
> 1.1 Lessen the gravity of (an offence or mistake):

The etymology suggests *softening action*:

> early 15c., "relieve (pain),"
>   from Latin mitigatus, past participle of mitigare "soften, make
>   tender, ripen, mellow, tame," figuratively, "make mild or gentle,
>   pacify, soothe,"
>   ultimately from mitis "gentle, soft"
>   (from PIE *mei- "mild") + root of agere "do, make, act" (see *[act](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=act&allowed_in_frame=0)*).
>   First element is from PIE root *mei- "soft, mild."

*[Mollify](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mollify)*:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   1.0 Appease the anger or anxiety of (someone):
>
> 1.1 rare Reduce the severity of (something):

The etymology suggests *to make soft*:

> late 14c., "to soften (a substance),"
>   from Old French mollifier or directly from Late Latin mollificare
>   "make soft, mollify"
>   from mollificus "softening,"
>   from Latin mollis "soft" (see *[melt](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=melt&allowed_in_frame=0)* (v.))
>   + root of facere "to make" (see *[factitious](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=factitious&allowed_in_frame=0)*).
>   Transferred sense of "soften in temper, appease, pacify" is recorded
>   from early 15c.
>   Related: Mollified; mollifying.

In definition and connotation, these two words share a lot in common, but [from the 16th century forward](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mitigate%2C%20mollify&year_start=1500&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmitigate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmollify%3B%2Cc0), the word *[mitigate](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mitigate%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)* has been applied more commonly to circumstances, while *[mollify](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mollify%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)* has been applied more commonly to hearts and minds.

Comment: You can't mitigate the damage your oil spill caused by cutting a check to everyone in town, but that'll sure mollify most citizens.